# VS MAC (Preview) : Project could not import WebApplication.targets

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to build a MVC project on OS X 10.12 using ***Visual Studio MAC (preview)***. I used git to transfer the source code from Windows to Mac OS X. I restored all the nuget packages successfully, but when I try to build the project I get a following error:

> Error:
>   WebService/WebService.csproj could not import
>   "$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   (WebService)

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Mac Preview

My issue was with Mono Framework, whenever I wanted to compile.
The solution for me was to switch on VS Settings/. Net Runtime and set Mono 4.8 as default.

Hope it helps